# Issues installing .pkg file on OS X

Tags: macos, xcode, cocoa

I'm having a real hard time installing an app I made for Mac. I created the package with Xcode 4.6.1 on OS X 10.8. I can run the `.pkg` fine on 10.8. The deployment target was set to OS X 10.7. However, on 10.7 it always say "can't be installed on this computer".

So I went in the build settings and changed the **Base SDK to 10.7, Build Active Architecture Only to NO (Debug and Release)**.

But I'm getting the same error.

Even in the terminal it won't install when running the following command:

```
sudo installer -pkg My.pkg -target /
installer: Error -  can’t be installed on this computer.
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

EDIT: I created a brand spanking new cocoa application in **Xcode 4.4** with no code but just the default. 
Set the deployment target to 10.7, base SDK to 10.7 and Build Active Architecture only to no and I'm still having the same exact issue ....